# Task Parallel is unstable, using 100% CPU at times

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, cpu-usage

I'm currently testing out Parallel for C#.  Generally it works fine, and using parallel is faster than the normal foreach loops.  However, at times (like 1 out of 5 times), my CPU will reach 100% usage, causing parallel tasks to be very slow.  My CPU setup is i5-4570 with 8gb ram.  Does anyone have any idea why this problem occurs?

Below are the codes I used to test out the function

```
            // Using normal foreach
            ConcurrentBag<int> resultData = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            foreach (var item in testData)
            {
                if (item.Equals(1))
                {
                    resultData.Add(item);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Normal ForEach " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // Using list parallel for
            resultData = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            sw.Restart();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, testData.Count() - 1, (i, loopState) =>
            {
                int data = testData[i];
                if (data.Equals(1))
                {
                    resultData.Add(data);
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine("List Parallel For " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // Using list parallel foreach
            //resultData.Clear();
            resultData = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            sw.Restart();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(testData, (item, loopState) =>
            {
                if (item.Equals(1))
                {
                    resultData.Add(item);
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine("List Parallel ForEach " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // Using concurrent parallel for 
            ConcurrentStack<int> resultData2 = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
            sw.Restart();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, testData.Count() - 1, (i, loopState) =>
            {
                int data = testData[i];
                if (data.Equals(1))
                {
                    resultData2.Push(data);
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Concurrent Parallel For " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // Using concurrent parallel foreach
            resultData2.Clear();
            sw.Restart();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(testData, (item, loopState) =>
            {
                if (item.Equals(1))
                {
                    resultData2.Push(item);
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Concurrent Parallel ForEach " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

### Normal output

Normal ForEach 493

List Parallel For 315

List Parallel ForEach 328

Concurrent Parallel For 286

Concurrent Parallel ForEach 292

### During 100% CPU usage

Normal ForEach 476

List Parallel For 8047

List Parallel ForEach 276

Concurrent Parallel For 281

Concurrent Parallel ForEach 3960

(This can occur during any of the parallel tasks, the above is only one instance)

### Update

By using the PLINQ method provided by @willaien and running it 100 times, this problem no longer occurs.  I still have no idea why this issue would surface in the first place though.

```
var resultData3 = testData.AsParallel().Where(x => x == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Mind moving away from `List<T>` (which is NOT threadsafe) to `ConcurrentBag<T>` (which IS threadsafe) to see what happens?

Comment: @willaien I changed resultData from List to ConcurrentBag, the problem still occurs.

Comment: I could reproduce this locally - it only happens when processing a large amount of elements. I have a strong feeling this is due to page faults

Comment: Any particular reason you're using the the `loopState` version of `.For` and `.ForEach` when you're not using it in the body?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, careful with `Parallel` - it doesn't shield you from thread safety issues. In your original code, you used non-thread-safe code when filling the list of results. In general, you want to avoid sharing any state (although the read-only access to the list is fine in a case like this). If you really want to use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` for filtering and aggregation (really, `AsParallel` is what you want in those cases), you should use the overload with thread-local state - you'd do the final results aggregation in the `localFinally` delegate (note that it's still run on a different thread, so you need to ensure thread-safety; however, locking is fine in that case, since you're only doing this once per thread, rather than on every iteration).

Now, the obvious first thing to try in a problem like this is to use a profiler. So I've done that. The results are as follows:

- There is hardly any memory allocations in either of those solutions. They are entirely dwarfed by the initial test data allocation, even for relatively small test data (I used 1M, 10M and 100M of integers when testing).
- The work being done is in the e.g. `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` bodies themselves, not in your code (the simple `if (data[i] == 1) results.Add(data[i])`).

The first means we can say GC probably isn't the culprit. Indeed, it doesn't get any chance to run. The second is more curious - it means that in some cases, the overhead of `Parallel` is way out of line - but it's seemingly random, sometimes it works without a hitch, and sometimes it takes half a second. This would usually point to the GC, but we've ruled that out already.

I've tried using the overload without the loop state, but that didn't help. I've tried limiting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, but it only ever hurt things. Now, obviously, this code is absolutely dominated by cache access - there's hardly any CPU work and no I/O - which will always favour a single-threaded solution; but even using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of 1 doesn't help - indeed, 2 seems to be the fastest on my system. More is useless - again, cache access dominates. It's still curious - I'm using a server CPU for the tests, which has plenty of cache for all of the data at once, and while we're not doing a 100% sequential access (which pretty much gets rid of the latency entirely), it should be quite sequential enough. Regardless, we have the base line of memory throughput in the single-threaded solution, and it's very close to the speed of the parallelised case when it works well (parallelised, I'm reading 40% less runtime than single-threaded, on a four-core server CPU for a embarassingly parallel problem - again, obviously, memory access is the limit).

So, it's time to check the reference source for `Parallel.For`. In a case like this, it simply creates ranges based on the amount of workers - one range for each. So it's not the ranges - there's no overhead from that.
 The core simply runs a task that iterates over the given range. There's a few interesting bits - for example, the task will get "suspended" if it takes too long. However, it doesn't seem to fit the data too well - why would something like this cause random delays unrelated to the data size? No matter how small the work job, and no matter how low `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is, we get "random" slowdowns. It might be a problem, but I have no idea how to check it.

The most interesting thing is that expanding the test data does nothing with the anomaly - while it makes the "good" parallel runs much faster (even getting close to perfect efficiency in my tests, oddly enough), the "bad" ones are still just as bad. In fact, in a few of my test runs, they are *absurdly* bad (up to ten times the "normal" loop).

So, let's have a look at the threads. I've artifically bumped the amount of threads in the `ThreadPool` to ensure that expanding the thread pool isn't a bottleneck (it shouldn't if everything worked well, but...). And here comes the first surprise - while the "good" runs simply use the 4-8 threads that make sense, the "bad" runs expand over all the available threads in the pool, even if there's a hundred of them. Oops?

Let's dive into source code once again. `Parallel` internally uses `Task.RunSynchronously` to run the root partitioned work job, and `Wait`s on the result. When I look at parallel stacks, there's 97 threads executing the loop body, and only one that actually has `RunSynchronously` on stack (as expected - that's the main thread). The others are plain threadpool threads. The task IDs also tell a story - there's *thousands* of individual tasks being created while doing the iteration. Obviously, something is *very* wrong here. Even if I remove the whole loop body, this still happens, so it's not some closure weirdness either.

Explicitly setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` offsets this somewhat - the amount of threads used doesn't explode anymore - however, the amount of tasks still does. But we've already seen that the ranges are just the amount of parallel tasks running - so why keep creating more and more tasks? Using the debugger confirms this - with MaxDOP of four, there's only five ranges (there's some alignment that causes the fifth range). Interestingly, one of the completed ranges (how did the first one finish so much ahead of the rest?) has index *higher* than the range it iterates - this is because the "scheduler" assigns range-partitions in slices of up to 16.

The root task is self-replicating, so instead of explicitly starting e.g. four tasks to handle the data, it waits for the scheduler to replicate the task to handle more data. It's kind of hard to read - we're talking about complex multi-threaded lock-less code, but it seems that it *always* assigns work in slices much smaller than the partitioned ranges. In my testing, the maximal size of the slice was 16 - a far cry from the millions of data I'm running. 16 iterations with a body like this is no time at all, which might lead to many issues with the algorithm (the biggest being the infrastructure taking more CPU work than the actual iterator body). In some cases, cache trashing might impact performance even further (perhaps when there's a lot of variation in the body runtimes), but most of the time, the access is sequential enough.

**TL; DR**

Don't use `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` if your work-per-iteration is very short (on the order of milliseconds). `AsParallel` or just running the iteration single-threaded will most likely be much faster.

Slightly longer explanation:

It seems that `Parallel.For` and `Paraller.ForEach` are designed for scenarios where the individual items you're iterating over take a substantial amount of time to execute (i.e. lots of work per item, not tiny amounts of work over a lot of items). They seem to perform badly when the iterator body is too short. If you're not doing substantial work in the iterator body, use `AsParallel` instead of `Parallel.*`. The sweetspot seems to be somewhere under 150ms per slice (around 10ms per iteration). Otherwise, `Parallel.*` will spend tons of time in its own code, and hardly any time doing your iteration (in my case, the usual number was somewhere around 5-10% in the body - embarassingly bad).

Sadly, I didn't find any warning about this on MSDN - there's even samples going over substantial amounts of data, but there's no hint at the terrible performance hit of doing so. Testing the very same sample code on my computer, I've found that it is indeed often slower than a single-threaded iteration, and at the best of times, barely faster (around 30-40% time savings *while running on four CPU cores* - not very efficient).

**EDIT:**

Willaien found a mention on MSDN about this very issue, and how to solve it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.110).aspx. The idea is to use a custom partitioner and iterate over that in the `Parallel.For` body (e.g. loop in `Parallel.For`'s loop). However, for most cases, using `AsParallel` is probably still a better choice - simple loop bodies usually mean some kind of a map/reduce operation, and `AsParallel` and LINQ in general are great at that. For example, your sample code could be rewritten simply as:

```
var result = testData.AsParallel().Where(i => i == 1).ToList();
```

The only case where using `AsParallel` is a bad idea is the same as with all the other LINQs - when your loop body has side-effects. Some might be tolerable, but it's safer to avoid them altogether.

Comment: I found an MSDN post that goes alongside your and my answers:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @willaien Ah, brilliant. Of course, it still means you probably want to use `AsParallel` - having to use a custom partitioner for a simple loop seems excessive. You could make a helper method, but really, simple loop bodies almost always mean you're basically doing a map/reduce, which `AsParallel` and LINQ in general handle well.

Comment: Can we get a TL;DR for the TL;DR?

Answer (score 1):

After some analysis, you're likely not even adding to these collections: 100,000,000 elements is still quite a bit smaller than the key search space (Approx. 2.1 billion), so these will likely not have any elements added, or just one or two.

As for the particular issue, while I'm able to replicate it, I'm unable to give a direct answer as to why this is happening, but, I suspect it has to do with heavy contention around the memory bus in some way, and how it handles the partitioning and thread creation. Limiting the number of threads to the current processor count seems to help, but, it doesn't solve the issue entirely.

All that said, a PLINQ version of things seems to be much faster and more consistent:

```
var resultData = testData.AsParallel().Where(x => x == 1).ToList();
```

**Edit:**
It looks like this is a semi-obscure, but known issue, more details are available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the problem no longer exists if I use this PLINQ expression (at least not in the 100 times I looped it).  I guess I will just have to avoid using For and Foreach for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I am using octa-core I5 processor with 16GB RAM, Parallel.Foreach was hitting 100% CPU, after making a minor code change CPU utilization came down to under 20%. This is my sample code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> values = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000).ToList();
        long sum = 0;

        Parallel.ForEach(values,
            new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
            x =>
            AddValues(x, ref sum)
            );
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }

    private static long AddValues(int x, ref long sum)
    {
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        CheckCPUUsageAndSleepThread(cpuCounter);

        int y = x * 5;            
        for (int i=0;i<y;i++)
        {
            CheckCPUUsageAndSleepThread(cpuCounter);
            //do nothing
        }
        return Interlocked.Add(ref sum, x);
    }

    private static void CheckCPUUsageAndSleepThread(PerformanceCounter cpuCounter)
    {
        if (cpuCounter.NextValue() > 80) //Check if CPU utilization crosses 80%  
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

When CPU utilization crosses 80% I pause for 1 millisecond.  This solved my problem. If you have a situation where you need to go with parallel.foreach loop, You could try calling this function, else you can try above solutions

> CheckCPUUsageAndSleepThread()

I hope it helps.

PS: To simulate 100% CPU usage comment *Thread.Sleep(1)*