# Linq Or IEnumerable taking Long to run when using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, ienumerable, parallel.foreach

I have an application that reads a csv (200 mb).

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();
```

The csv stores pricing information and has around 500k records in it.
The code snippet below when calling StoreValues takes around 18 seconds.
Is there a way to speed this up ?

distinctMarketIds = 54 int values
The lines collection will have 500k lines and each line [0] has marketId which im matching.

```
IEnumerable<string[]> newList = (lines.Where(t => distinctMarketIds.Contains(t.Split(',')[0]))
                                      .Select(t => t.Split(',')));

log.Info(("Time Taken To Get Filtered Prices " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds +" seconds."));

StoreValues(newList, file); //store the prices
log.Info(("Time Taken To Store Prices " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
```

The Store value Method uses `Parallel.ForEach`

```
Parallel.ForEach(finalLines, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxThreads }, (line) =>
{
});
```

I cannot seem to find why it would take 18 seconds to go through this loop.
I have tested on another machine with similar specs and it takes 2.5 seconds for StoreValue Method

```
#region LoadPriceDataFromCsvFile

        public int LoadPriceDataFromCsvFile(string filename, string[] marketIdList, int maxThreads)
        {
             MaxThreads = maxThreads;
             int filteredRows = 0;
             string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filename, "*.csv");
            elapsed.Start();
            log.InfoFormat("Total Csv files to Scan {0}",files.Length);
            Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxThreads }, (file) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    log.InfoFormat("About to Scan File {0}", file);
                    ScanCsvFilesAndGetPrices(file);
                }
               catch (System.OutOfMemoryException e)
               {
                  log.Info(e);
               }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Info(e);
                }

            });


            return PriceCollection.Count;
        }

        #endregion

#region ScanCsvFilesAndGetPrices
        private void ScanCsvFilesAndGetPrices(string file)
        {
            try
            {

                log.Info(("Time Taken " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
                var lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();
                log.Info(("Time Taken To Read csv " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));

                if (lines.Any())
                {
                    log.Info(("Time Taken To Read Any " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
                    var firstLine = lines.ElementAt(1); // This is the First Line with Headers
                    log.Info(("Time Taken To Read First Line " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
                    var lastLine = lines.Last(); // This is the Last line in the csv file
                    log.Info(("Time Taken To Read Last Line " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
                    var header = lines.First().Split(',');
                    log.Info(("Time Taken To Split Header Line " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));

                    GetIndexOfFields(header);
                    log.Info(("Time Taken To Read Header " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
                    // Get the Publish Date Time
                    if (PublishedDatetime_Index != -1)
                    {
                        var fLine = firstLine.Split(',');
                        var lLine = lastLine.Split(',');

                        var firstLineDatetime = (fLine[PublishedDatetime_Index].Contains("+"))? fLine[PublishedDatetime_Index].Remove(fLine[PublishedDatetime_Index].IndexOf("+",StringComparison.Ordinal)): fLine[PublishedDatetime_Index];
                        var publishDateTimeFirstLine =FileNameGenerator.GetCorrectTime(Convert.ToDateTime(firstLineDatetime));

                        string lastLineDatetime = (lLine[PublishedDatetime_Index].Contains("+"))? lLine[PublishedDatetime_Index].Remove(lLine[PublishedDatetime_Index].IndexOf("+",StringComparison.Ordinal)): lLine[PublishedDatetime_Index];
                        var publishDateTimeLastLine =FileNameGenerator.GetCorrectTime(Convert.ToDateTime(lastLineDatetime));
                        // check if the order execution date time of any order lieas between the date time of first and last line of csv so we can add that csv to our filtered list


                        string[] distinctMarketIds = OrderEntityColection.FindAll(obj =>obj.OrderLastChangeDateTimeUtc >= publishDateTimeFirstLine &&obj.OrderLastChangeDateTimeUtc <= publishDateTimeLastLine).Select(obj => obj.MarketId.ToString())
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToArray();

                        log.InfoFormat("Total Markets Identified {0}",distinctMarketIds.Length);

                        List<OrderEntity> foundOrdersList = OrderEntityColection.FindAll(obj =>obj.OrderLastChangeDateTimeUtc >= publishDateTimeFirstLine &&obj.OrderLastChangeDateTimeUtc <= publishDateTimeLastLine);

                        lock (FoundOrdersList)
                        {
                            FoundOrdersList.AddRange(foundOrdersList);
                        }
                        log.InfoFormat("Total Orders Identified {0}", FoundOrdersList.Count());

                        log.Info(("Time Taken To Read Execution Times and Market " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds +" seconds."));
                        if (distinctMarketIds.Length != 0)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<string[]> newList =
                                                            (lines.Where(
                                                                t => distinctMarketIds.Contains(t.Split(',')[0]))
                                                                .Select(t => t.Split(','))
                                                                );

                            log.Info(("Time Taken To Get Filtered Prices " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds +" seconds."));
                            // this is taking longer than expected. Somthing to do with IEnumerable<string[]> 
                            StoreValues(newList, file); //store the prices
                            log.Info(("Time Taken To Store Prices " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));



                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Info(e);
            }

         }


        #endregion

#region GetIndexOfFields

        // These are the fields we want to Look for from the headers and accordingly get their location
        private void GetIndexOfFields(IEnumerable<string> lineHeader)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var column in lineHeader)
            {
                if (column == "MarketId")
                {
                   MarketId_Index= index;
                }
                if (column == "Bid")
                {
                    Bid_Index = index; ;
                }
                 if (column == "Ask")
                {
                    Ask_Index = index; 
                }
                 if (column == "Mid")
                {
                    Mid_Index = index;
                }
                 if (column == "Is_Indicative")
                {
                    Is_Indicative_Index = index;
                }
                 if (column == "Price_Engine")
                {
                    Price_Engine_Index = index; 
                }
                 if (column == "PublishedDatetime")
                {
                    PublishedDatetime_Index = index; 
                }
                 if (column == "Market_Is_Open")
                {
                    Market_Is_Open_Index = index; 
                }
                 if (column == "AuditId")
                {
                    AuditId_Index = index; 
                }
                 if (column == "Row_Update_Version")
                {
                    Row_Update_Version_Index = index; 
                }
                 if (column == "DontPublish")
                {
                    DontPublish_Index = index; ;
                }
                index++;
            }


        }

        #endregion

        #region StoreValues

        private void StoreValues(IEnumerable<string[]> finalLines, string file)
        {

            log.InfoFormat("total Finel Lines Sent for Storing {0}", finalLines.Count());

            Parallel.ForEach(finalLines, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxThreads }, (line) =>
               {
                   var prices = new Prices();
                  // the code that you want to measure comes here
                  var datetime = (line[PublishedDatetime_Index].Contains("+")) ? line[PublishedDatetime_Index].Remove(line[PublishedDatetime_Index].IndexOf("+", StringComparison.Ordinal)) : line[PublishedDatetime_Index];


                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(datetime))
                   {
                       prices.PublishedDatetime = Convert.ToDateTime(datetime);
                   }

                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[MarketId_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.MarketId = Convert.ToInt32(line[MarketId_Index]);
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Bid_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Bid = Convert.ToDecimal(line[Bid_Index]);
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Ask_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Ask = Convert.ToDecimal(line[Ask_Index]);
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Mid_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Mid = Convert.ToDecimal(line[Mid_Index]);
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Is_Indicative_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Is_Indicative = Convert.ToBoolean(line[Is_Indicative_Index]);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       prices.Is_Indicative = false;
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Price_Engine_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Price_Engine = Convert.ToString(line[Price_Engine_Index]);
                   }

                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Market_Is_Open_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Market_Is_Open = line[Market_Is_Open_Index] == "1";
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[AuditId_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.AuditId = Convert.ToString(line[AuditId_Index]);
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[Row_Update_Version_Index]))
                   {
                       prices.Row_Update_Version = Convert.ToString(line[Row_Update_Version_Index]);
                   }
                   if (!IsNullOrEmpty(line[DontPublish_Index]))
                   {
                       if (DontPublish_Index != 0)
                       {
                           prices.DontPublish = line[DontPublish_Index] == "1";
                       }
                   }
                   prices.SbProdFile = file;

                   lock (PriceCollection)
                   {
                       PriceCollection.Add(prices);
                   }
               });

        }
```

Comment: Post the full code of storevalues method not just an empty foreach and if it runs faster on another machine ITS NOT THE CODE

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` on a single file? What is `finalLines`?

Comment: Have you tried any profiling? There should be much better ways of doing this.

Comment: Im new to this forum and also not an experienced dev . I can attached the .cs file if needed

Comment: what is `distinctMarketId` ... and you are parsing each line twice.

Comment: btw, `newList` isn't executed until the first `Parallel.ForEach` within `StoreValues(...)`

Comment: If you are writing to a file the `Parallel.ForEach` will not improve performance but may cause the lines to be written in the wrong order.

Comment: The final results are all good. Its just the Linq bit where i get the filtered lines and pass to store values takes 18 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, get rid of the lock and the `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: So i have 500k lines in a csv that has pricing information for stocks
I then have 8000 order objects that i have to find execution against from this file
I get distinct marketids for the orders i specify based on execution time of orders.(whid i got from db)
Once i have distinct market ids (file can have 200 market id data but my order market id could be 50 lets say so not interested in 200 markets)
Then for Lines, im trying to find all lines where the Lines[0] matches any of the distinct market ids

Comment: I then pass this filtered list (which would have 58 columns ) to create another list where im only interested in 10 cols  for each market found

Comment: I need Parallel for in there as currently im only scanning one file but i could be scanning 100 files located in a directory

Comment: Wow... you are scanning these files way too many times.

Comment: Then read them in parallel but write synchronously. Using a `lock()` in a `Parallel.ForEach()` seems pointless.

Comment: The `ScanCsvFilesAndGetPrices` method opens each the file 5 times and 2 of those are full file scans.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is not a good choice when the items take very little time to process (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041631/task-parallel-is-unstable-using-100-cpu-at-times/32049057#32049057). If each individual record takes less than a couple milliseconds to process, you'll be spending more time on `Parallel.ForEach` overhead than actually processing. Using it for processing individual files is also a mistake - I/O can easily be done asynchronously, no need to waste threads waiting for I/O; and you could easily be saturating the I/O already anyway, making things even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't see how `Parallel.ForEach` could help to improve performance when you need to process a single file
- Don't use `File.ReadLines(file).ToList()`, either use `ReadAllLines` if you want all lines in memory or use `ReadLines` if you want to process the lines one after another
- Why do you split the line multiple times?
- Use a `HashSet<string>` for `distinctMarketIds`:

This should be more efficient:

```
var marketIdSet = new HashSet<string>(OrderEntityColection.FindAll(obj =>obj.OrderLastChangeDateTimeUtc >= publishDateTimeFirstLine &&obj.OrderLastChangeDateTimeUtc <= publishDateTimeLastLine).Select(obj => obj.MarketId.ToString()));
IEnumerable<string[]> allFields = File.ReadLines(file)
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Where(arr => marketIdSet.Contains(arr[0]));
```

Note that due to deferred execution of `Select` and `Where` this is just a  query, it is yet not executed. So whenever you will use `allFields` you will execute this query again. So it's a good idea to create a collection, f.e. with `allFields.ToList()` which you pass to `StoreValues`:

```
StoreValues(allFields.ToList(), file); //store the prices
```

If you pass a collection you could really benefit from using `Parallel.ForEach` in `StoreValues`.

Comment: Using Parallel.ForEach because i would be scanning around 100 files. the cs file would have pricing data starting from 00:00 lets say to 23:59. Im only interested in csv files where my order execution lies within that time. So i check first line (get the column value dor publishedDatetime) and also last line. I then check my order execution time and if it lies within those times, then order would have executed using prices within that csv file.  Deffered execution seems to be causing the delay as when i pass the IEnumerable<string[]> as ToList(), it takes time to convert it first

Comment: @user1535623: deferred execution is not causing the delay, if you call `ToList` the query is executed. Look at my comments and also the last line which i've just added.

Comment: Tim: Manage to cut down 8-9 seconds with your approach :) Finally i have with your help  cut it down to 10 seconds but again it should be 2.5 to 3 seconds max . Any other useful suggestions

Comment: @user1535623 you probably can make it faster if your tasks within the `Parallel.ForEach()` would be longer. Each tasks is very short so the overhead of executing a task on the threadpool is too high. So instead of running parallel foreach on `IEnumerable<string[]>` You could try to group some lines. For example `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string[]>>`, for example: `var result = list.Select((item, index) => new {item, index}).GroupBy(itemWithIndex => itemWithIndex.index % 16);`

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    //var lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();

    // this is just a fast generation for sample data
    var lines = Enumerable.Range(0, 500000)
                            .Select(i => string.Join(",", i % 7, i, i & 2))
                            .ToList();

    // HashSet will work as an indexed store and will match faster in your loop
    var distinctMarketIds = new HashSet<string>{
        "0", "2", "3", "5"
    };

    // Do this if you are to use the method syntax instead of the query syntax
    // var newList = lines.Select(l=>l.Split(','))
    //                    .Where(ps=>distinctMarketIds.Contains(ps[0]));

    var newList = from l in lines
                  // this will parse the string once versus twice as you were doing before
                  let ps = l.Split(',')
                  where distinctMarketIds.Contains(ps[0])
                  select ps;

    // can't see the content of your `StoreValues` method but writing to a 
    //    file in parallel will never work as expected.  
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter("outfile.txt"))
        foreach (var l in newList)
            stream.WriteLine(string.Join(";", l));

}
```